# For loop breaking out instead of repeating

Tags: java

I'm writing code to create a java template library.  I'm writing a specific piece of code where a reader will read the text of the template and pull out placeholders ("${placeholder}).  So far, when Jtesting, it seemed to work with a single placeholder, but when I try more than one, the code doesn't seem to loop back and read the rest of the template.

I can't, for the life of me, see why the code is failing.

I've debugged the code, and all I can see is that when it stored the first placeholder, it's not looping back, but instead it's dropping out.

Code is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class placeholderFinder {
    private Reader reader;

    public placeholderFinder(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public static final int NORMALTEXT = 0;
    public static final int PLACEHOLDERTEXT = 1;

    private int state = NORMALTEXT;
    private StringBuilder placeholder = new StringBuilder();

    public String nextPlaceholderFinder() throws IOException {
        for (int p = reader.read(); p != -1; p = reader.read()) {
            if (p == '$') {
                if (state == NORMALTEXT) {
                    state = PLACEHOLDERTEXT; 
                    placeholder.append((char) p);
                } 
            } else if (state == PLACEHOLDERTEXT) {
                        placeholder.append((char) p);
                    }

            if (p == '}') {
                    if (state == PLACEHOLDERTEXT) {
                        state = NORMALTEXT;
                        String placeholderStore = placeholder.toString();
                        placeholder.setLength(0);
                        return placeholderStore;

                    }

                }

            }

        return null;

    }

}
```

And the Jtest

```
@Test
void testWithPlaceholders() throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new StringReader("a ${name} ${date}");
    placeholderFinder finder = new placeholderFinder(reader);
    String expectedresult = "${name}${date}";
    String actualcode = finder.nextPlaceholderFinder();
    assertEquals(expectedresult, actualcode);
```

Comment: The problem is that you return from the loop when a `}` is encountered after a `$`.

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. Call this function once per placeholder, not once for all placeholders. So, first time you'll get ${name}, and the second time you'll get ${date}

Comment: OK.... any tips, as I'm still pretty new to all this java malarkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution return after the first placeholder is found, you can change it to go through all the characters in the `reader` before returning. Here is an example:

```
public String nextPlaceholderFinder() throws IOException {
    for (int p = reader.read(); p != -1; p = reader.read()) {
        if (p == '$') {
            if (state == NORMALTEXT) {
                state = PLACEHOLDERTEXT; 
                placeholder.append((char) p);
            } 
        } else if (state == PLACEHOLDERTEXT) {
            placeholder.append((char) p);
        }
        if (p == '}') {
            if (state == PLACEHOLDERTEXT) {
                state = NORMALTEXT;
            }
        }
    }
    return placeholder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why you only find one placeholder (like `${name}`) is, that you make a return statement as soon as you find a `}` symbol.
In this line:

```
return placeholderStore;
```

Try to put the temporary result of this first placeholder into a list, like this one:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And instead of returning the placeholderStore you put it into the list:

```
results.add(placeholderStore);
```

And when you've read the whole text (no matter what it contained actually) you return this list of results (and change the return type of your method). Or you join the list again:

```
String.join("", results);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give that a go